# How to remove the last two occurrences of "-" character of a string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have an array of strings that are formatted as such:

```
Ado-trastuzumab emtansine(HER2)02-22-2013
```

I would like to remove the last two "-" symbols only (from the date part of the original string) so that the name of the drug (Ado-trastuzumab emtansine) is not altered. Right now my regex removes all "-" symbols:

```
foreach my $string (@array) {
     $string =~ tr/-//d;
}
```

I would like the output to instead be the following:

```
Ado-trastuzumab emtansine(HER2)02222013
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wouldn't that be the last two `'-'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substr` as an lvalue to only apply the transliteration to a particular part of your string:

```
substr($string, -10, 10) =~ tr/-//d;
```

In this case, on the last 10 letters of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Good to know about the substr function.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach my $string (@array) {
    $string =~ s/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$/$1$2$3/;
}
```

Comment: Please *don't* use `\1` etc. `$1` is the correct form for a reference to a capture. [`perlre` has a specific warning about it](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241)

Answer (score 1):

To do what you say literally - remove the last two hyphens from a string - you could write this

```
$string =~ s/-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\z/$1$2/;
```

But in this case you could simply remove all hyphens that follow a digit:

```
$string =~ s/\d\K-//g;
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing should be done when there's only one `-`:

```
$s =~ s/-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\z/$1$2/;

$s = reverse($s);
$s =~ s/^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-/$1$2/;
$s = reverse($s);

$s = reverse( reverse($s) =~ s/^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-/$1$2/r );  # 5.14+
```

All these work even if there is only one `-`:

```
$s =~ s/-([^-]*)(?:-([^-]*))?\z/$1$2/;

$s =~ s/-([^-]*)\z/$1/ for 1..2;

$s =~ s/^.*\K-//s for 1..2;

$s = reverse($s);
$s =~ s/-// for 1..2;
$s = reverse($s);

$s = reverse($s);
$s =~ s/^([^-]*)-(?:([^-]*)-)?/$1$2/;
$s = reverse($s);

$s = reverse( reverse($s) =~ s/^([^-]*)-(?:([^-]*)-)?/$1$2/r );  # 5.14+
```

For long strings, the `reverse` solutions should be much faster. For the short strings, go for readability.